# How do I make my 3d cube move left and right with buttons in Unity with RigidBody.AddForce?

Tags: unity, android, movement

How do I make my 3d cube move left and right with buttons in Unity with `RigidBody.AddForce()`?
I can't figure out how to do this in Unity!
I'm trying to make my game playable on Android but I can't get my cube to move with buttons!

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. It would help if others could see the code that you have thus far.

Comment: This seems to be something that is covered by [*many* tutorials and guides a simple search away](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+move+with+addforce&oq=unity+move+with+addforce) - what do you need us to explain that hasn't already been explained many times before?

Comment: i dont really understand any of it, ive looked at all of the posts and i dont know how to implament that to my own likeing

Comment: Can you explain to us where specifically you get lost? If a dozen different authors talking about the topic haven't been clear for you so far, then we have a very high probability of making the same mistakes they did: explaining the topic in the same way that you already find unhelpful. So, walk us through how you understand the subject so far, how you've tried putting these guides into practice, and where specifically you run into trouble. With that detail, we can tailor our explanations to what you really need, rather than just rehashing stuff that's already out there.

Comment: Basically the other ones wouldn't start from the start, so IDK what to do with the code they found that fixed it. So can you explain how to do it from the start, please?

Comment: sorry, I just don't really know what I need specifically. all I can say is can you explain from the start or just guide me, please.

Comment: You can search for "create a physics object unity". Here's a [sample link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTGcs10Sj34)". Watch / read a few tutorials, and if needed go into the basics more. At this point you need to learn about the physics system instead of adding force to objects. Also, the physics system has friction, your object could just be not moving because of that, or a lack of RigidBody.